# How to check the network connectivity of micro services within EKS CLI

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, devops

I have microservices running within EKS 1.22.
Is there a possible way to check the microservice communication also pod-to-pod communication within the cluster through CLI?

Comment: By "CLI" you mean [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or [Kubernetes CLI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/)? What exactly do you mean by check micro-service communication - you want to make sure that they can communicate with each other?

Comment: Kubernetes CLI ---- "you want to make sure that they can communicate with each other"---> Yes I want to verify their connectivity across the namespaces and same namespaces also pod-to-pod communication can we verify the communication via eth0 of pods??

Answer (score 3):

Everything out of the box should work properly (assuming you have [AWS EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/)).

I think this article - [Debug Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/) has very helpful hints.

Let's first check pod to pod communication using trival method - `ping` command. I created two NGINX deployments (one in default namespace, second one in namespace `test`):

```
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx -n test
```

Now I will check IP addresses of both of them:

```
user@shell:~$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP
nginx-6799fc88d8-jxpj4   1/1     Running   0          3m13s   172.17.0.2
```

And also in `test` namespace:

```
user@shell:~$ kubectl get pods -o wide -n test
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP
nginx-6799fc88d8-z2glk   1/1     Running   0          103s   172.17.0.4
```

Now I will [execute into one pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/) and check connectivity to the second one:

```
user@shell:~$ kubectl exec -it nginx-6799fc88d8-jxpj4 -- sh
# apt update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
...
All packages are up to date.
# apt-get install inetutils-ping
Reading package lists... Done
...
Setting up inetutils-ping (2:2.0-1) ...
# ping 172.17.0.4
PING 172.17.0.4 (172.17.0.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.123 ms
```

Okay, so the pod to pod connection is working. Keep in mind that container images are minimal, so you may install `ping` as I did in my example. Also, depending on your application you can use different methods for checking connectivity - I could use `curl` command as well and I will get the standard NGINX home page.

Now time to create [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) (I am assuming this is what you mean by microservice) and test connectivity. Service is an abstract mechanism for exposing pods on a network. So we can test connectivity either by getting list of endpoints - IP address of the pods associated with this service - `kubectl get endpoints my-service`, and then checking pod to pod connection like in previous example, or we can just `curl` service IP  address/hostname. For hostname between namespaces it's little bit different! Check below:

Let's create deployments with 3 replicas:

```
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx --replicas=3
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx --replicas=3 -n test
```

For each deployment we will [create service using `kubectl expose`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/#creating-a-service-for-an-application-running-in-five-pods):

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx --name=my-service --port=80
kubectl expose deployment nginx --name=my-service-test --port=80 -n test
```

Time to get IP addresses of the services:

```
user@shell:~$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   64d
my-service   ClusterIP   10.107.224.54   <none>        80/TCP    12m
```

And in `test` namespace:

```
user@shell:~$ kubectl get svc -n test
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
my-service-test   ClusterIP   10.110.51.62   <none>        80/TCP    8s
```

I will exec into pod in default namespace and `curl` IP address of the `my-service-test` in second namespace:

```
user@shell:~$ kubectl exec -it nginx-6799fc88d8-w5q8s -- sh
# curl 10.110.51.62
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
```

Okay, it's working... Let's try with hostname:

```
# curl my-service-test
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: my-service-test
```

Not working... why? Let's check `/etc/resolv.conf` file:

```
# cat resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search test.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

It's looking for [hostnames only in namespace where pod is located](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-work-by-dns-name).

So pod in the `test` namespace will have something like:

```
# cat resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search test.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

Let's try to curl `my-service-test.test.svc.cluster.local` from pod in default namespace:

```
# curl my-service-test.test.svc.cluster.local
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
```

It's working.

To sum up:

- communication between pods in cluster should work properly between all namespaces (assuming that you have proper [CNI plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) installed, on AWS EKS you have)
- pods containers are in most cases Linux containers so just use [Linux tools](https://geekflare.com/linux-test-network-connectivity/) to check connectivity (like `ping` or `curl`)
- Services are an abstract mechanism for exposing pods on a network, you can connect to them for example using `curl` command
- IP addresses are cluster wide, hostnames are namespace wide - if you want to connect to the resource from the other namespace you need to use fully-qualified name (it applies for services, pods...)

Also check these articles:

- [Access Services Running on Clusters | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/)
- [Service | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)
- [Debug Services | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/)
- [DNS for Services and Pods | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)